# Run-instances in another region without changing aws configuration

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, aws-regions

I would like to run an EC2 in another region without having to change aws configuration. This is a script that should run for other users as well.
I know that it is possible to create an SG in another region just by passing the argument `--region us-east-2` .. but doesn't work for Runinstances api.

Another solution would be a script that runs `aws configure` and change ONLY the region, without any input from the user. any idea on how to implement any of these 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

`--region` works for all aws cli commands. It is a top-level parameter documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-options.html). If that isn't working for you, you should show the details of that in your question.

Also, `aws configure` only sets the **default** region. You can override the current region at any time by setting the `AWS_REGION` environment variable. You could do this inside your script before calling aws cli commands.

See the [aws cli environment variable documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html).

Comment: Thank you Mark, i'm currently configured as `us-east-1` and when i run `aws ec2 run-instances --region us-east-2 --image-id ami-04899638f181c1fb0 --keyname ec2keypair` i get an error: `An error occurred (Unsupported) when calling the RunInstances operation: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.`

Comment: Are you sure the AMI with that ID, and the keypair with that name, exist in `us-east-2`?

Comment: The ami you've selected might not be compatible with the default `m1.small` instance type.